# Twilio conference call participants can able to see other participants numbers or not?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to integrate Twilio call and conference call, before that I have few doubts on it.

While conference call time one participants can able to see other participants real numbers or not? If possible, how to restrict that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

With a conference call, your participants will only see one number, the Twilio number that they called or that you make calls from.

With regular calls, you have the option to set a [`callerId`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#callerid) when you forward a call. If you don't set this, then the incoming caller ID is used and the number will be shared with the person being called. If you set the `callerId` to a Twilio number, then the person being called will only see the Twilio number.

If you are looking to build masked number/anonymous communications, then I recommend you take a look at [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy) which can handle all of this for you too.